# Microsoft Bot Framework - Sending a message during a dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am creating a simple high low chat bot, using Microsoft's [Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/), that makes you guess a random number. I've decided to use recursive dialogs; however, whenever I send a message using *session.send* it ends the dialog. How can I send a message that doesn't end the dialog?

```html
bot.add('/max-num', [
 function (session) {
  builder.Prompts.number(session, "What's the max number?")
 },
 function (session, results) {
  var max = results.response;
  session.userData.max = max;
  session.userData.num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * max)
  session.userData.round = 1;
  session.send("I choose a number between 1 and " + max + " inclusively!");
  session.replaceDialog('/round');
 }
]);
bot.add('/round', [
 function (session) {
  builder.Prompts.number(session,"Guess a number")
 },
 function (session, results) {
  // function vars
  var round = session.userData.round;
  var target = session.userData.num;
  var guess = results.response;
  
  // high/low logic
  if (guess === target) { // Winning Case
   session.send("Wow you got it in " + round + (round === 1 ? "round" : "rounds"));
   session.endDialog();
  } else { // Losing case
   if (guess > target)
    session.send("Your guess was too high!");
   else if (guess < target)
    session.send("Your guess was too low!");

   session.replaceDialog("/round");
  }
 }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prompt user for an input and wait for users input builder.Prompts.text(), or you can start a child dialog, which can use session.send("") end itself and return back to the parent.